# The meaning of "ところ" in context

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, expressions

I am having a difficult time understanding the meaning of "ii tokoro" in the context of this sentence.

The full sentence(s) in which I am translating is as follows:

"おっと、いいところに。
今日 は新しいムービーを撮るみたいなんや。"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It essentially means `How convenient!`. It's a short form for `いいところに来たね`. The literal meaning is `Ah, you came to an opportune occasion`.